# $d$-dimensional Fourier transform of $\cos|x|$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory

What is the $d$-dimensional Fourier transform of $\cos|x|$? More specifically, what does
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\text{d}^dx\cos|x|e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}\ ,
$$
where $|x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+\dots+x_d^2}$,
evaluate to?
I know that the Fourier transform of $e^{-t|x|}$ with positive $t>0$ gives me the Poisson kernel (c.f. [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/96365) on MO) and I would like to know if there exists a generalization to imaginary $t$.

**Addendum**

For $d=1$ the above integral reduces to the Fourier transform of the ordinary cosine. It can be expressed via the delta distribution
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{d}x\cos x\,e^{-ikx}=\pi\big(\delta(k-1)+\delta(k+1)\big)\ ,
$$
as can be seen by applying the inverse transformation to the r.h.s.
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\text{d}k\,\pi\big(\delta(k-1)+\delta(k+1)\big)e^{ikx}=\frac12\big(e^{ix}+e^{-ix}\big)=\cos x\ .
$$

For completeness I include here a dodgy calculation for the $d=3$ case. Help from someone who actually knows about distributions is needed.

We can use spherical coordinates to obtain
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\text{d}^3x\cos|x|e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}=&\,2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}\text{d}r\int_{-1}^{1}\text{d}(\cos\theta)\,r^2\cos r\,e^{-ikr\cos\theta}\nonumber\\
=&\,2\pi\int_0^\infty\text{d}r\,r^2\cos r\,\frac{1}{ikr}\big(e^{ikr}-e^{-ikr}\big)\nonumber\\
=&\,\frac{4\pi}k\int_{0}^\infty\text{d}r\,r\cos r\sin kr\nonumber\\
=&\,\frac{4\pi}k\int_0^\infty\text{d}r\,-\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\frac12\Big[\cos\big(r(1+k)\big)+\cos\big(r(1-k)\big)\Big]\nonumber\\
=&\,-\frac\pi k\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\text{d}r\,\frac12\Big[e^{ir(1+k)}+e^{-ir(1+k)}+e^{ir(1-k)}+e^{-ir(1-k)}\Big]\nonumber\\
=&\,-\frac{2\pi^2} k\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\big[\delta(1+k)+\delta(1-k)\big]\ .
\end{align}
Thus we finally obtain
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\text{d}^3x\cos|x|e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}=\frac{2\pi^2}{k}\big(\delta'(1-k)-\delta'(1+k)\big)\ .
$$

Comment: The function is not integrable.

Comment: This has to be done in a distributional sense. Maybe try it in  $\mathbb{R}$ first.

Comment: @Aruralreader maybe I should have mentioned that I am aware of the $d=1$ case.

Comment: For those of us, me especially, who don’t know this from that, please tack that result and derivation onto your question.

Comment: @Aruralreader I have added the 1-dimensional case. As you mentioned, it results in a distribution.

Comment: I'm a bit confused over the term $\delta'(1+k)$ in the $d=3$ case. Since $k\geq 0$ that term will vanish. Yet I'm not confident with just dropping it.

Comment: @md2perpe I was wondering about that term too and it indeed just vanishes when we apply the inverse Fourier transformation to obtain $\cos |x|$. It does, however, make the distribution even under $k\to-k$ as it should be right? (since $\cos$ is even.)

Comment: Haven't we already assumed that the Fourier transform is spherically symmetric, i.e. that it only depends on the norm of $\vec k$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question which I would like to share with those interested.
For odd dimension $d$ we have
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\text{d}^dxe^{ifx}e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}=(-2\pi)^{\frac{d-1}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{k}\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\right)^{\frac{d-1}{2}}\left[\pi\big(\delta(f+k)+\delta(f-k)\big)-\frac{2if}{f^2-k^2}\right]\ ,
$$
where $x=|\vec{x}|$ and $k=|\vec{k}|$.
It might even be applicable to all dimensions if one defines the fractional derivative in some way.

**Derivation**

Starting with
$$
I(\vec{k})=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\text{d}^dxe^{ifx}e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}=(2\pi)^{\frac{d}{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\text{d}r\,\left(\frac{r}{k}\right)^{\frac{d-2}{2}}re^{ifr}J_{\frac{d-2}{2}}(kr)\ ,
$$
where $J_\nu$ denotes the $\nu$-th Bessel function of the first kind, we can use
$$
J_{\nu+m}(z)=(-1)^{m}z^{\nu+m}\left(\frac1z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^{m}\big(z^{-\nu}J_\nu(z)\big)
$$
with $\nu=-1/2$ and $m=(d-1)/2$ to write
$$
I(\vec{k})=(-1)^{\frac{d-1}{2}}(2\pi)^{\frac{d}{2}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{1}{k^{d-1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\text{d}r\,r^{d-1}e^{ifr}\left(\frac1r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)^{\frac{d-1}{2}}\cos(kr)\ .
$$
Expanding
$$
\left(\frac1r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)^{n}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j^{(n)}r^{-(2n-j)}\frac{\partial^j}{\partial r^j}\ ,
$$
where the coefficients $a_j^{(n)}$ satisfy the relation
$$
a_j^{(n)}=a_{j-1}^{(n-1)}-\big[2(n-1)-j\big]a_j^{(n-1)}\ ,\quad a_1^{(1)}=1\ ,\ a_0^{(n)}=a_{n+1}^{(n)}=0\ ,
$$
we can calculate (using the shorthand $n=(d-1)/2$)
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{r}{k}\right)^{2n}\left(\frac1r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)^{n}\cos(kr)=&\,\left(\frac{r}{k}\right)^{2n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j^{(n)}r^{-(2n-j)}(ik)^{j}\frac12\big(e^{ikr}+(-1)^{j}e^{-ikr}\big)\nonumber\\
=&\,\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j^{(n)}k^{-(2n-j)}\frac{\partial^{j}}{\partial k^{j}}\frac12\big(e^{ikr}+e^{-ikr}\big)\nonumber\\
=&\,\left(\frac1k\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\right)^{n}\cos(kr)\ .
\end{align}
(Is there a more obvious way to see this?)
With that we obtain
$$
I(\vec{k})=(-1)^{\frac{d-1}{2}}(2\pi)^{\frac{d-1}{2}}\left(\frac1k\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\right)^{\frac{d-1}{2}}\int_0^\infty\text{d}r\,e^{ifr}\big(e^{ikr}+e^{-ikr}\big)\ .
$$
For the integral over $r$ we now use
$$
\int_0^\infty\text{d}r\,e^{iar}=\pi\delta(a)+\frac{1}{ia}
$$
to finally arive at
$$
I(\vec{k})=(-2\pi)^{\frac{d-1}{2}}\left(\frac1k\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\right)^{\frac{d-1}{2}}\left[\pi\big(\delta(f+k)+\delta(f-k)\big)+\frac{1}{i(f+k)}+\frac{1}{i(f-k)}\right]\ ,
$$
which gives the desired result.

**Connection to the Poisson kernel**

One nice thing about the above result is that it can be connected to the Poisson kernel mentioned in my original question. To see this we let $f=i\beta$ for some positive $\beta>0$ such that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\text{d}^dxe^{-\beta x}e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}=(-2\pi)^{\frac{d-1}{2}}\left(\frac1k\frac{\partial}{\partial k}\right)^{\frac{d-1}{2}}\left[\pi\big(\delta(i\beta+k)+\delta(i\beta-k)-\frac{2\beta}{\beta^2+k^2}\right]\ .
$$
Focusing on what used to be the imaginary part of the answer and using
$$
\frac1k\frac{\partial}{\partial k}=2\frac{\partial}{\partial(k^2)}
$$
we obtain
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\text{d}^dx\,e^{-\beta x}e^{-i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{x}}=-\frac{(2\pi)^d}{\pi^{\frac{d+1}{2}}}\Gamma\left(\frac{d+1}{2}\right)\frac{\beta}{(\beta^2+k^2)^{\frac{d+1}{2}}}\ ,
$$
which is precisely the Poisson kernel (up to a negative sign which I would be very happy if someone can point to where it comes from).

Comment: You might add a reference or derivation.

Comment: @Aruralreader I added the derivation.

Comment: Thank you very much.